# Multiple if and elsif statements

Tags: algorithms, loops, algorithmic

I would like to know how best I can get this algorithm written, I tried multiple times with the implementation below but it did not generate the algorithm I wanted.

```
 \begin{algorithm} %[H]
        \caption{message}
        \label{alg:ALG1}
\begin{flushleft}
        \textbf{INPUT:} ce, tp_{av} $X$ \\
        \textbf{OUTPUT:}  message \textit{msg}
        $U_{ce_{i}} \gets num(U)$  \\
        $rs_{n} \gets [rs_{1},rs_{2},...,rs_{9} ]$  \\
$\delta \gets [0:10]$  \\
$\rho \gets [0:10000]$  \\
\end{flushleft}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \ForAll{$$x in \Omega$$}{
                \IF{$rs_{n} > rs_{s}$}
                    \IF{$tp_{av,ce_{n}} > tp_{av,ce_{s}}$}
                    \ENDIF
                    \IF{$U_{ce_{n}} < 10 $} \\
                        \state $msg \gets \{$x, ce_{n}$ \}$
                    \ENDIF
                \ELSIF{$$|rs_{n} - rs_{s}|$$ in $$\delta$$}{
                    \IF{$$tp_{av,cell_{n}} \geq tp_{av,ce_{s}}$$}
                    \ENDIF
                    \IF{$U_{ce_{n}} < 10 $} \\
                         $$ msg \gets \{x, ce_{n} \}$$
                         }
                    \ENDIF
                \ELSIF{$$|rs_{n} - rs_{s}|$$ in $\delta$}{
                    \IF{$ |tp_{av,ce_{n}} - tp_{av,ce_{s}}|$ in $\rho$}
                    \ENDIF
                    \IF{$U_{ce_{n}} < 10 $} \\
                            \state $msg \gets \{x, ce_{n}\}$
                            } 
                    \ENDIF
            
                \ENDIF
                    }
            \EndFor
        \end{algorithmic}
 \end{algorithm}
```

I only ended up getting something like shown below.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Welcome to TeX-LaTeX StackExchange!

Usually you are expected to provide as much information as possible for people

- to know exactly what you are doing/trying under what conditions (what TeX-engine—could, e.g., be TeX or pdfTeX or LuaTeX or XeTeX, what format—could, e.g., be LaTeX or plain TeX or ConTeXt, what documentclass, what packages etc you are using; version-numbers sometimes are of interest, too),
- to be able to reproduce problems under the same conditions under which you encounter them,
- to have precise information about the look of the text of warnings/error-messages that might occur on the console/in the .log-file.

Often things don't work out. Thus you are not expected to deliver a Minimal Working Example, but you are expected to deliver a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

With LaTeX you can do this by eliminating by and by everything that is not needed for reproducing error-messages/erroneous behavior.

You are a new contributor and this is your first question here, so I will do some guessing. ;-)

In case my guesses are wrong consider editing your question and phrasing the question more precisely, providing not just a snippet of code but everything that is needed (`\documentclass{...}`, `\usepackage{...}`, `\begin{document}`, `\end{document}`, etc) so that readers can attempt to reproduce the problems encountered by you just by copy-pasting the code provided to a new file on their own machine and running TeX/LaTeX/ConTeXt/⟨whatever TeX-engine and format shall be used for compiling⟩.

---

You did not reveal what package(s) you use for typesetting algorithms.
I assume you use the LaTeX 2ε-packages *algorithm* and *algpseudocode*.

You can redefine keywords via `\algrenewcommand`.

With the names of LaTeX-macros the lettercasing does matter.
I.e., macros `\IF`, `\ELSIF`, `\ENDIF` and `\state` are not defined by the package algpseudocode, but the macros `\If`, `\ElsIf`, `\EndIf` and `\State` are.

I did not grasp exactly what algorithm you'd like to type, but the following might be a starting-point for seeing how LaTeX-code might look like:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

% The phrases usually are in lowercase letters.
% Let's redefine them in uppercase letters:
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{\textbf{END}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicdo{\textbf{DO}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicwhile{\textbf{WHILE}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textbf{FOR}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicforall{\textbf{FOR ALL}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicloop{\textbf{LOOP}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrepeat{\textbf{REPEAT}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicuntil{\textbf{UNTIL}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicprocedure{\textbf{PROCEDURE}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{\textbf{FUNCTION}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{\textbf{IF}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicthen{\textbf{THEN}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{\textbf{ELSE}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{REQUIRE:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{ENSURE:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicreturn{\textbf{RETURN}}
\algrenewcommand\textproc{\textsc}

\DeclareMathOperator{\num}{num}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm} %[H]
  \caption{message}%
  \label{alg:ALG1}%
  \textbf{\rlap{INPUT:}\hphantom{OUTPUT: }}$ce$, $tp_{av}X$ \\
  \textbf{OUTPUT: }\vtop{%
     \hbox{message \vtop{%
                      \hbox{$msg$ $U_{ce_{i}} \gets \num(U)$}%
                      \hbox{$rs_{n} \gets [rs_{1},rs_{2},...,rs_{9} ]$}%
                      \hbox{$\delta \gets [0:10]$}%
                      \hbox{$\rho \gets [0:10000]$}%
                   }%
     }%
  }%
  \smallskip\hrule\smallskip
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \ForAll{$x \in \Omega$}
      \If{$rs_{n} > rs_{s}$}
        \If{$tp_{av,ce_{n}} > tp_{av,ce_{s}}$}
        \EndIf
        \If{$U_{ce_{n}} < 10 $}
          \State $msg \gets \{x, ce_{n} \}$
        \EndIf
      \ElsIf{$|rs_{n} - rs_{s}| \in \delta$}
        \If{$tp_{av,cell_{n}} \geq tp_{av,ce_{s}}$}
        \EndIf
        \If{$U_{ce_{n}} < 10 $}
          \State $msg \gets \{x, ce_{n} \}$
        \EndIf
      \ElsIf{$|rs_{n} - rs_{s}| \in \delta$}
        \If{$ |tp_{av,ce_{n}} - tp_{av,ce_{s}}|$ in $\rho$}
        \EndIf
        \If{$U_{ce_{n}} < 10 $}
          \State $msg \gets \{x, ce_{n}\}$
        \EndIf
      \EndIf
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the much elaborate response.

Comment: @kekule You are welcome. If there are questions about the code or about how to change/adapt things, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @kekule Notice in lines 14 and 15 two variants of writing "in". In line 14 Giuseppe Peano's "element of"-symbol "∈" is used in the sense of "in the set/element of the set". In line 15 the letter sequence "in" is used in the sense of "in the range/interval".  (But an interval can be considered a set, so the ∈ notation probably is possible even if the focus is not on set theory...)

Comment: This explanation clears my doubts. I have been able to adapt it to my situation and everything is good.  But do you know why the error message "Missing \endcsname  inserted" sometimes occur in \State or \For line??    By the way thanks once more

Comment: @kekule When I compile my example on my system I don't get such error-messages. The code-snippets provided by you are not sufficient for me to reproduce the problem. If you make a minimal reproducible example exhibiting the problem, i.e. which can be compiled for obtaining the error-message, I can take a look at it. Basically TeX "expects"  between `\csname` and matching `\endcsname`  to find characters or tokens whose expansion yields characters so that you have a sequence of characters suitable for making the name of a control-sequence. If there is a primitive like `\hskip`, ...

Comment: @kekule ... it is not suitable for forming the name of a control-sequence any more and you get this error-message. But without seeing your code I cannot track down how this situation comes into being. When TeX attempts to auto-resolve the situation by itself inserting `\endcsname` before the token not suitable as component of the name of a control sequence, you often get subsequent error-messages about spurious `\endcsname` because the `\csname` written into the code was matched by the `\endcsname`  automatically inserted by TeX so that `\endcsname` written into the ...

Comment: @kekule ... code seems to be spurious. You often get this error when using `\label{...}` or `\(page)ref{...}` with an argument that is not suitable as the name of a control-sequence-token.

Comment: Well understood.  I have been able to fixed everything now. Thank you very much, you have really explained it very well. I do appreciate.